# Using WPS with Airport Utility for other then adding Printers

Tags: wifi, airport

If you open the `Airport Utility` on you Mac, there is a option `Add WPS Printer`.

Since Apple explicitly named it `Add WPS Printer...`, can you use this for **other** devices then Printers?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can!

### I tested this with:

- `Airport Utility` v6.3.8 (on macOS 10.13.2)
- With a `Airport Extreme 802.11ac`

### Devices Tested & Working

- TV Sony Bravia (via **First Attempt**)
- TV LG WebOS v3.5 (via **PIN**)
- Printer Brother MFC9320CW (via **PIN**)

*Although I'm not sure if it works with everything, I'm fairly positive it will work for many other devices that support WPS.*